# Java SQL Derby Getconnection illegal modifier

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, connection, derby

I have been learning how to get SQL Derby installed and running, and I looked at google and didn't find anything useful that could fix this problem. In the line: Connection getConnection() I get the error: "Illegal modifier for parameter getConnection; only final is permitted" What is wrong? It gives me the same error even if I move the code over to a different class. It is derby on eclipse in java, and I did everything in creating and connecting the database. I have not imported any reference libraries or software pluggins. I updated the DTP. I used the vogella tutorial for databases and eclipse. I have also installed Derby several times over the course of a couple months, but never seem to be able to get a separate java project to connect properly. Once again, my issue is the getConnection giving me an error. I have a comment in the area of the problem.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Properties;


public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //******************************************************
        //The issue is the getConnection() 
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        //*******************************************************
        Connection conn = null;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\Users\\Josiah\\MyDB",    connectionProps);

        System.out.println("Connected to database");
        return conn;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to define your `getConnection` method nested inside the `main` method - this is not allowed in Java.

Move the method to be outside of main:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      ... main method code
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\Users\\Josiah\\MyDB",    connectionProps);

        System.out.println("Connected to database");
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, just for learning about Derby (and about Java), you don't even really need a separate method; you could just include your code right in your "main" method.